# Program type already present: com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am integrate the Facebook authentication in react-native. I am use package:- [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk). I am get the error in my android studio. Error:

> Error: Program type already present: com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0"
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
}
```

Package versions:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-native-debugger": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-google-signin": "^1.0.2"
```

Comment: try removing the last line `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'`. Isn't it supposed to be added with `react-native-fbsdk`?

Comment: I am also its try but not solve the error